# How to create a form with dependent fields? (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering how to create a form that displays field dependent on the fields selected beforehand. For example: if Coffee is selected as a drink, only then do I want to allow sugar and milk amounts to be input.

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="field">
    Drink: <%= f.select :drink, ['Coffee', 'Orange Juice', 'Tea'], id: 'extended_list' %><br />
    </div>
    Coffee Type: <%= f.select :coffee_type, ['Espresso', 'Cappuccino', 'Filter', 'Greek', 'Frappe', 'Latte'] %><br />

    Sugar Amount: <%= f.select :sugar_amount, ((1..5).map {|i| [i,i] } << ["None",nil]) %><br />

    Milk Amount: <%= f.select :milk_amount, ((1..5).map {|i| [i,i] } << ["None",nil]) %><br />
    <% end %>
      <%= f.button :submit, class: "button is-info" %>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to wrap the fields you'd like to hide in a div. Add a distinct id to each of them.

For example, if you want to hide coffee_type, you can add the id "js-coffee-type" to it.

Also, add a class (for instance, `d-none`, as used by Bootstrap) so we can hide it using CSS.

```
    <%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        Drink: <%= f.select :drink, ['Coffee', 'Orange Juice', 'Tea'], id: 'extended_list' %><br />
      </div>

      <div id="js-coffee-type" class="d-none">Coffee Type: <%= f.select :coffee_type, ['Espresso', 'Cappuccino', 'Filter', 'Greek', 'Frappe', 'Latte'] %></div>
      <div>Sugar Amount: <%= f.select :sugar_amount, ((1..5).map {|i| [i,i] } << ["None",nil]) %></div>
      <div>Milk Amount: <%= f.select :milk_amount, ((1..5).map {|i| [i,i] } << ["None",nil]) %></div>

      <%= f.button :submit, class: "button is-info" %>
    <% end %>
```

In the same file, you can write the CSS code that hides this field.

```
    <style>
    .d-none { display: none; }
    </style>
```

Now you can write the JS code to toggle the class depending on the first field.

```
    <script>
    $("#extended_list").change(function() {
      var drink = $("#extended_list").val();

      if (drink == "Coffee") {
        $("#js-coffee-type").removeClass("d-none");
      } else {
        $("#js-coffee-type").addClass("d-none");
      }
    });
    </script>
```

These are not best practices but they should do the work.

Comment: I'm having trouble removing the "d-none" class now. I'm not sure if the javascript is receiving the drink value correctly.

Comment: Can you add a line with `alert($("#extended_list").val())`? What does it say?

Comment: I figured out the problem, the syntax should be  $("#js-coffee-type").removeClass("d-none"); instead of  $(".js-coffee-type").removeClass("d-none");